# How to add the list which does not starts with date python 3?

Tags: python

How to add the list which does not start with date python 3?

Add the sub list which does not start with date

```
import  re
from datetime import datetime
l = [["01/01/2001","words1"],["words2","words3"],["words4"],["03/03/2003","words5","words6"],["words7"]]


def extract_description_words_bet_date_date(nn_lst):
    date_list = []
    str_list = []

    for elem in nn_lst:
        try:
            datetime.strptime(elem[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
            date_list.append(elem)
        except ValueError:
            str_list.append(elem)
            pass
    return str_list

list2 = extract_description_words_bet_date_date(l)

print(list2)
```

Expected output : `[["01/01/2001","words1"],["words2","words3","words4"],["03/03/2003","words5","words6"],["words7"]]`

Actual output : `[['words2', 'words3'], ['words4'], ['words7']]`

Comment: did you try anything for it?

Comment: yes please see  the code again @  Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: what's wrong with the current code you have?

Comment: i got the output as [['words2', 'words3'], ['words4'], ['words7']]... but i want output as  [["01/01/2001","words1"],["words2","words3","words4"],["03/03/2003","words5","words6"],["words7"]] @  Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: you said `add the list which does not starts with date python 3?` and `[['words2', 'words3'], ['words4'], ['words7']].` is such a list, which you get in your output, what is the issue here?

Comment: i want to merge the list which does not starts with date and insert to the mergerd list again to the nested list

Comment: please see my actual output and expected output

Comment: that's not very clear from the question, please reword it to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question isn't very clear, here's the solution you're probably looking for

```py
from datetime import datetime
l = [["01/01/2001","words1"],["words2","words3"],["words4"],["03/03/2003","words5","words6"],["words7"]]


def extract_description_words_bet_date_date(nn_lst):
    new_list = []

    for elem in nn_lst:
        try:
            datetime.strptime(elem[0], "%d/%m/%Y")
            new_list.append(elem)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                if len(new_list) == 0:
                  new_list.append(elem)
                else:
                  datetime.strptime(new_list[-1][0], "%d/%m/%Y")
                  new_list.append(elem)
            except ValueError:
                new_list[-1] = new_list[-1] + elem
                pass
    return new_list

list2 = extract_description_words_bet_date_date(l)

print(list2)
```

Comment: The output is incorrect: the second item should be `["words2", "words3", "words4"]` but it's `["words2", "words3", "words4", "words4"]`.

Comment: @MaxiMouse Is it? I'm getting the proper output [here](https://repl.it/repls/BelatedPlayfulPostgres)